# C malloc valgrind - uninitialised memory in my singly linked list implementation

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, valgrind, singly-linked-list

I tried to implement a singly linked linked List in c. I wanted to be able to use multiple instances of the list and I wanted to create the list in the main function. That is why i chose to implement it in the way I did.

The code works perfectly fine but i am concerned because of the output valgrind creates. Also I tried to use the code in a project on an embedded system and strange errors happen.

The valgrind output is:

> starting...
>
> ==3570== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
>
> ==3570==    at 0x100000E8E: push_cfront (in ./map_test)
>
> ==3570==    by 0x100000D4F: main (in ./map_test)
>
> ==3570==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
>
> ==3570==    at 0x100008EBB: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.11.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
>
> ==3570==    by 0x100000E80: push_cfront (in ./map_test)
>
> ==3570==    by 0x100000D4F: main (in ./map_test)
>
> ==3570==
>
> ...finished

Also it tells me that i am loosing one block. Where do i make a mistake freeing it

> ==3570== LEAK SUMMARY:
>
> ==3570==    definitely lost: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
>
> ==3570==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>
> ==3570==      possibly lost: 2,064 bytes in 1 blocks
>
> ==3570==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>
> ==3570==         suppressed: 24,525 bytes in 186 blocks

Please give me a hint on where i went wrong.

test.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "command_list.h"    
int main() {

    printf("starting...\n");

    Clist * command_list = malloc(sizeof(Clist));
    if (command_list == NULL) printf("Malloc Failed\n");
    command_list->head = NULL;

    //push_cback(command_list, 0);
    push_cfront(command_list,1);

    free_clist(command_list);
    free(command_list);
    printf("\n...finished\n");
    return 0;
}
```

command_list.h:

```
#ifndef __COMMAND_LIST_H
#define __COMMAND_LIST_H

typedef struct cnode {
    uint8_t command;
    struct cnode * next;
} Cnode;

typedef struct clist {
    Cnode * head;
} Clist;

void push_cback(Clist * list, uint8_t command);
void push_cfront(Clist * list, uint8_t command);
void free_clist(Clist * list);

#endif
```

command_list.c

```
void push_cfront(Clist * list, uint8_t command){
    Cnode * new_node;
    new_node = malloc(sizeof(Cnode));
    if (new_node->next == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    new_node->command = command;
    new_node->next = list->head;
    list->head = new_node;
}

void free_clist(Clist * list){
    if (list->head == NULL){
        return; //already empty
    }
    Cnode * current = list->head;
    while (current->next != NULL){
        Cnode* temp = current->next;
        free(current);
        current = temp;
    }
    free(current);
    list->head = NULL;
}
```

Comment: On the third line of `push_cfront ` you do `if (new_node->next == NULL)` you just `malloc`ed that thing; `next` isn't set. Pretty sure you meant to use `if (new_node == NULL)`.

Comment: Oh, and props for using Valgrind.

Comment: I think you should check for `list==NULL`, just in case :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems.  You are checking `new_node->next` (uninitialized data in malloc'd memory) instead of `new_node` (the return value of malloc).  On my computer at least this also causes memory not to be freed because by chance `new_node->next` is null so you return without freeing `new_node`.  Also, if you want to support pushing to the back of a linked list, you should consider a circularly linked list because it allows that operation without having to traverse the whole thing.

Finally, a few tips: it's good that you are using valgrind, but it will be more helpful if you compile with `-g` to enable debugging symbols so valgrind will tell you line numbers.  Also, when I make linked lists, I like to use a dummy head node for some operations to avoid a special case for empty or singleton lists.  For inserting into a sorted linked list, that technique looks like:

```
int sorted_insert(Clist *list, char new_command){
    Cnode _head = {NULL, list->head}, *head = &_head, *prev = head, *tmp;//head is an auto dummy node obviating null checks.
    int ord = -1;//If there are no existing nodes, newObj would be less than all objects.
    while(prev->next && (ord = (int)newObj - prev->next->command)) > 0){//Iterate by prev->next not curr to use only one pointer.
        prev = prev->next;//Looping while there is a next node and its data compares less than new_command.
    }
    if((!ord) || !(tmp = malloc(sizeof(Cnode))){//newObj is already in the list or allocation failed.
        return 0;
    }
    *tmp = (Cnode){.next=prev->next, .command=new_command};
    prev->next = tmp;
    list->head = head->next;//un- add head which is then deallocated by stack frame cleanup.
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That made it clearer why sometimes i lost some blocks and sometimes not. 
Actually I did compile the program with -g and also i used valgrind with this command valgrind --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes

Answer (score 0):

The `new_node->next` is uninitialized when you check it's value. You don't need that.

If you look for `malloc` failures, set a return code for the function and check it upon invocation.

Until that, the `if` branch in `push_cfront` is not needed.

... or you wanted to check `list->head` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Also there's a problem with this piece of code in `push_cfront`

```
new_node = malloc(sizeof(Cnode));
if (new_node->next == NULL) {
    return;
}
```

It's undefined behaviour since `new_node` memory is not initialised. You probably wanted to check `if (new_node == NULL)` to see if memory was actually allocated.

Comment: Ok thanks to everyone for pointing out the problem with checking new_node->next. I don't see the problem i had with my free method. I freed the remaining node after the while loop. Actually i think you try to free null in your free_clist() method. Or am i wrong?

Comment: @lugges oh, you're right. Missed free(current), will look more into this, I'll delete the part about free_clist for now from the answer